# rxjs delayWhen with debounce removes last item of the observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to dealy the output of an observable after that observable stop the emission for 3 second... So i used delayWhen(x=>originalObservable.pipe(debounceTime(3000)))...
Why item C is lost? ...

```js
//in$ is a Subject

in$.pipe(
  tap(x=> log(4,'item '+x.name+' arrived, wait debounce time...') ),
  delayWhen( () => in$.pipe(debounceTime(3000)) ),
  tap(x=> log(4,'debounce time passed for item '+x.name+', go ahead...'))
).subscribe

//the log is
/*
itme A arrived, wait debounce time...
itme B arrived, wait debounce time...
itme C arrived, wait debounce time...
debounce time passed for item A, go ahead...
debounce time passed for item B, go ahead...
*/
```

Comment: why not using `delayWhen( () => timer(3000))`?

Comment: I need to dealy the output of an observable after that observable stop the emission for 3 seconds, not only after 3 seconds

Comment: i figured out that the debounce take the last item... so this is not the right way to do what i need

Answer (score 0):

solved...

```js
let lastTicTime:number;

in$.pipe(
  tap(x=> {
    lastTicTime = Date.now();
    console.log('item'+x.name+' arrived, wait debounce time... ')
  } ),
  delayWhen( () => interval(1000).pipe(
    map(()=> ( Date.now() - lastTicTime ) > cfg.inputDelay ),
    filter(x => x === true ),
    tap(x=>console.log('timer done'))
  ) ),
  tap(x=> console.log('debounce time passed for '+x.name+', go ahead...'))
)
```